# How to define n-th parent element by pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

As in the title,
how can i define nth parentElement in js in other way than:

```
var theComment = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
```

Comment: the most practical option would be to give that element a class and use `e.target.closest('.comment')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a loop for it:

```js
const n = 4
let elem = e.target
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
  elem = elem.parentElement
console.log(elem)
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, if you're looking for a specific element, it might be better to just write a selector for the element you're looking for.

This applies to your case even more, as `event.target` can return  child nodes of the watched element (if the event bubbles), making your parent count shift around a bit.

Comment: Your code will raise an error if the given element has less than four parent nodes.

Comment: @LuizFelipe So will doing `e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement`. I assumed that's ensured to be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You might define a function which ascends up in the parent hierarchy with a loop, e.g.:

```
function nthParent(n, el) {
  while (n--) {
    el = el.parentElement;
    if (!el) return null;
  }
  return el;
}
```